# Can I install iphone application developed in iphone sdk 3.1.3 on iphone3.0?

Tags: iphone, installation

I am having unlocked iphone 3.0 which I want to use for the development purpose. But my problem is I have iphone sdk 3.1.3 installed on my mac.

So can I install iphone application developed in iphone sdk 3.1.3 on iphone 3.0....

Can anyone help me with this.....

Thanx in advace......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two settings that control this the Base SDK and iPhone OS Deployment Target, both accessible in Project settings within XCode.

You want to keep your Base SDK set to the latest stable version at all times and then set your deployment target to the older version you want to support.

In this case:

Base SDK = 3.1.3

iPhone OS Deployment Target = iPhone OS 3.0

This is the practice recommended by Apple.  If there are features that you want to use that are available in the newer SDK but not in an older version you can test specifically for those features.

Answer (score 1):

U can compile your application directly for the iphone 3.0 OS using your 3.1.3 SDK.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. May be not exactly with the same SDK version, but it's widespread practice to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to do this here: [Specifying the Buildtime Environment](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Running_Applications/running_applications.html) (in the Setting the Base SDK section).