# Can a user install iphone application developed using 3.1.3 in his iphone 3.0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, installation

Can a user install my application from iTunesStore if he is having iPhone OS 3.0 or having lower version of iPhone OS and I have developed my application using iPhone SDK 3.1.3...

Can anyone help me with this...

Thanx in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I install iphone application developed in iphone sdk 3.1.3 on iphone3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299806/can-i-install-iphone-application-developed-in-iphone-sdk-3-1-3-on-iphone3-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you projects settings, use a build setting named "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to specify your minimal iPhone OS version.

To do that, double click the blue project icon (at the top of the project’s "Groups and Files" table), click the "Build" tab and find the setting in the "Deployment" settings section.

To use features from a later iPhone OS, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986589/how-do-you-optionally-use-iphone-os-3-0-features-in-a-2-0-compatible-app).

Answer (score 3):

If you compile your application to target iPhone OS 3.1.3 then it will not run on 3.0 - instead the user will get a message telling them to update their OS when they try to install.

However, there's a good chance that you will be able to compile your app to target 3.0 as long as you're not using any specific 3.1+ and newer features. To do so, just change the Active SDK you target in Xcode before you compile. Then your app will run on both 3.0 and 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

If you set your Target SDk in Xcode to 3.1.3, you may be using features of the SDK not found on an iPhone running a lower OS.  However, you can test for those features in your program and take alternative measures if the user does not have those features/frameworks available.  There is nothing that will prevent your app from running on older iPhone OSes, other than the fact that using new features will cause the app to fail.

On the other hand, you use the Deployment SDk value of XCode to limit which iPhone OSes can actually run your app.  This way you can limit the app to be available to only iPhones with later OS and not the earlier ones.  The Apple iTunes App Store will use the Deployment SDk value to tell the user who is purchasing, what the minimum system requirement is too.